# What does the $-1$ mean in $2\mu g/L^{-1}$

Tags: chemistry

What does the $-1$ mean in the expression $2\mu g/L^{-1}$? Does it literally mean multiply by $-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2\mu g/L$ or $2\mu g L^{-1}$ means $2$ micrograms per litre. I don't think anyone would write $2\mu g/L^{-1}$, though that (in the weird situation) would be equivalent to $2\mu gL$.

The $-1$ refers to the exponent of $L$ in the unit. For any nonzero real number $a$, $a^{-1}$ can be taken to mean $\frac1a$.

Comment: 2μg/L or 2μgL−1 are the same? How can that be? I can't rationalise that.

Comment: So does that not mean that it is simply creating fractions?

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. I have read a research paper where it's denoted as 2μg/L^-1 , is that specific a rarity?

Comment: I think in the paper with $\mu$g/L$^{-1}$ it is an error.  Someone intended $\mu$g/L but then switched to the equivalent $\mu$gL$^{-1}$ but forgot to complete the change.